Looking for an example where the format string G yields a different output than the format string F (Enum format strings C#)
Here is a MRE:
FileAccessPermissions permissions = FileAccessPermissions.Read | FileAccessPermissions.Special;

Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("F"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("D"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("X"));

[Flags]
enum FileAccessPermissions
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Execute = 4, 
    Delete = 8,
    Special = 16,
    ReadWrite = Read | Write,
}

To my surprise, I can't find a singular example where the format specifier G and the F yield different outputs.
I get this for this example:
Read, Special
Read, Special
17
00000011

If I do:
FileAccessPermissions permissions = FileAccessPermissions.ReadWrite;
I get:
ReadWrite
ReadWrite
3
00000003


if I get you right, you're asking how the formatters Fand G differ, correct?

Have you read this already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings#g-or-g

((DayOfWeek)7).ToString("G") will return "7", but ((DayOfWeek)7).ToString("F") will return "Monday, Saturday".

If you remove the [Flags] attribute, then the two format specifiers will give you different values for eg: (FileAccessPermissions)17:
FileAccessPermissions permissions = (FileAccessPermissions)17;
    
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("F"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("D"));
Console.WriteLine(permissions.ToString("X"));

enum FileAccessPermissions
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Execute = 4, 
    Delete = 8,
    Special = 16,
    ReadWrite = Read | Write,
}

Output:
17
Read, Special
17
00000011

From the documentation:

G or g
If the Flags attribute isn't set, an invalid value is displayed as a numeric entry.
F or f
If the value can be displayed as a summation of the entries in the enumeration ... the string values of each valid entry are concatenated together, separated by commas.


It's literally mentioned in the docs:
Console.WriteLine(((DayOfWeek)7).ToString("G"));

returns 7, while
Console.WriteLine(((DayOfWeek)7).ToString("F"));

returs Monday, Saturday.
In your case both are identical, because your enum is marked with FlagsAttribute. However for the G-modifier, the summation of multiple values is only displayed as string, when the enum is marked with Flags, otherwese it'll be displayed as a number:

If the enumeration is defined with the FlagsAttribute set, the string
values of each valid entry are concatenated together, separated by
commas. If the Flags attribute isn't set, an invalid value is
displayed as a numeric entry

vs

as a summation of the entries in the enumeration (even if the Flags
attribute isn't present), the string values of each valid entry are
concatenated together, separated by commas

